# AudioInputStream - Seek Faster

Tags: java

I have an [AudioInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioInputStream.html) **that does not support skip()**. It is backed by jflac.

Therefore, I am using a `read ( byte[] )` call, and dumping the data, to jump forward through the file.

Unfortunately, it takes about 1 second to seek through 17MB (about .25 seconds to seek a minute) which is too slow for my purposes.

Is there anything I can do to try to seek through a file faster?  I would need something about 20-30x as fast as what I currently have in order to have a nice user experience.

Here is my code:

```
private void openStreamsAtRequestedOffset ( ) {
    encodedInput = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream( file );

    AudioFormat baseFormat = encodedInput.getFormat();
    AudioFormat decoderFormat = new AudioFormat(
            AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, baseFormat.getSampleRate(),
            16, baseFormat.getChannels(), baseFormat.getChannels() * 2,
            baseFormat.getSampleRate(), false );

    decodedInput = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream ( decoderFormat, encodedInput );

    if ( seekRequestPercent != NO_SEEK_REQUESTED ) {
        long seekPositionByte = getBytePosition ( file, seekRequestPercent );
        int bytesRead = 0;

        byte[] skippedData = new byte[ 256 ];
        while ( bytesRead < seekPositionByte ) {
            int bytesSkipped = decodedInput.read ( skippedData );
            bytesRead += bytesSkipped;
        }
    }

    DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info ( SourceDataLine.class, decoderFormat );
    audioOutput = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
    audioOutput.open( decoderFormat );
}
```

I tried reading more and less than 256 bytes, it didn't seem to have any meaningful impact.

I also tried opening the file with a BufferedInputStream, calling `skip()` on that, and then passing the BufferedInputStream to `AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream()` a few different ways, but those failed as well. Whenever I called skip, jflac claimed that the stream had been closed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Very very great question. What solution you finally found :) ?

Comment: I now use vlcj for audio decoding, which depends on native VLC libraries to decode. Prior to that, you can see my two flac solutions here. These were not perfect -- I still couldn't decode 24 bit flacs, for example: https://github.com/JoshuaD84/HypnosMusicPlayer/tree/3df230056d87e0587fbe167e709a4a00f20138a1/src/net/joshuad/hypnos/audio/decoders

look at BackupFlacDecoder, FlacDecoder, and FlacDecoderLogic.

Comment: If you want to use the VLC solution, check out the most recent commit in that project, which includes stripped down native libraries that need to be bundled. I've found it to be a much better solution.

Comment: Here is a link to my decoding systems now. As you can see, its pretty simplified. Added about 20MB overhead to my project, but it was well worth it: https://github.com/JoshuaD84/HypnosMusicPlayer/tree/master/src/net/joshuad/hypnos/audio

Comment: That's amazing, Joshua i am also making a player in JavaFX you can take any code if you like have a look https://github.com/goxr3plus/XR3Player. I will definitely read your repository code to study it :)

Comment: Followed on github. We can probably help each other's projects out a lot. :)

Comment: Yep exactly :) :) ::

Answer (score 1):

You should certainly not try to roll your own when [`AudioInputStream.skip()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioInputStream.html#skip(long)) already exists. If you have one that desn't support it, complain to the vendor. All of to has do to do is call `skip()' on the underlying stream, which as it is a file input stream should be instantaneous.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I guess I'm not surprised that it's somewhat slow. 17MB / 256 bytes is 66406 loop iterations of a fairly slow I/O operation.

---

You said

> I tried reading more and less than 256 bytes, it didn't seem to have
>   any meaningful impact.

But looking at the documentation, it seems that the amount of bytes you're able to read each time can change.

> public int available() throws IOException
>
> Returns the maximum number of bytes that can be read (or skipped over)
>   from this audio input stream without blocking.

Even if the following is not any faster, it should at least be more correct:

```
long seekPositionByte = getBytePosition ( file, seekRequestPercent );
int bytesRead = 0;

byte[] skippedData = new byte[ decodedInput.available() ];
while ( bytesRead < seekPositionByte ) {
    int bytesSkipped = decodedInput.read ( skippedData );
    bytesRead += bytesSkipped;
}
```

It may be prudent to also check that it doesn't overshoot by too far.

Comment: Yea, I wrote that first. It potentially loops forever with this library.  When it goes to read the last small count of bytes, if the request is small enough, it reads zero instead and the loop continues.  My guess is this is because music files are expressed as frames. In either case, although this code isn't "correct" it is accurate enough for seeking through a music track (as long as I make sure I don't read past the end, which is pending.)

Comment: And, for now, I'm focused on the big problems. If this code takes seconds to execute, it's going in the trash and I'll have to find another solution.   I can track down the cause of that read issue later, and I can think of a few ways to manage it, but it's not important at all until the code is something more than a prototype.

Comment: "And, for now, I'm focused on the big problems" Well yes, but if `decodedInput.available()` were sufficiently large (and, crucially, worked) then it probably wouldn't take seconds.

Comment: Sounds like you may need to just find a better underlying library.